# PHP mail () activation

Tags: php, function, email, shared, activation

I need to activate this mail() function is there any way of doing this only on my hosting account (being on shared account)?

Thanks!

Comment: this kind of questions must be directed to your Webhost Support, not to SO

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this a case of the `mail()` function not operating? Most shared hosting accounts have it enabled. The only people who have the option to make that kind of change to the server configuration (as far as I know) is the Server Admin.

If you are sure that the `mail()` function is not available on your account, contact your Webhost Support and ask them about it.