# php form works on one site but not another

Tags: php, wordpress

I've been using the same contact form for quite a while:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit']) ) {
    $name = $_POST['names'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];
    $robot = $_POST['robot'];
    $from = 'online@domain.co.uk'; 
    $to = 'info@domain.co.uk'; 
    $subject = 'Online Enquiry';
    $headers = "From: DOMAIN <no-reply@domain.co.uk> \r\n";
    $headers .= 'Reply-To:'. $email . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion(); // Sender's Email

    $body = "From: $name\n E-Mail: $email\n Message:\n $message";
} ?>
<?php if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
if ($name != '' && $email != '' && $message !='') {
    if ($robot != 'yes') {               
        if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $headers)) { 
            echo '<p class="approved"><strong>Your message has been submitted</strong></p>';
        } else { 
            echo '<p class="warning"><strong>Something went wrong!</strong></p>'; 
        } 
    } else if ($_POST['submit'] && $robot == 'yes') {
        echo '<p class="warning"><strong>Looks like you are spam!</strong></p>';
    }
} else {
    echo '<p class="warning"><strong>Please complete all fields.</strong></p>';
    }
} 
?>
    <form id="contact" method="post" action="#contact">

    <label>Name</label>
    <input name="names" type="text" placeholder="NAME">

    <label>Email</label>
    <input name="email" type="email" placeholder="EMAIL">

    <label>Message</label>
    <textarea rows="10" name="message" placeholder="MESSAGE"></textarea>
    <input id="capture" name="robot" type="checkbox" value="yes">        
    <input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">

</form>
```

It works absolutely fine on other sites but doesn't work on one domain? submit simply returns the error  "Something went wrong!". the site is on the same cloud server as many of the other sites that work fine. It's driving me mad because I cant see an error.

Turning debugging on I get the error:
Notice: Undefined index: robot in /form-contact.php on line 6

Ive tried removing the robot check all together and it still doesn't work, but generates no error when debugging?

Can anyone offer any advice?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3186725/how-can-i-get-the-error-message-for-the-mail-function

Comment: Maybe you have not activated yet the funct email on your php.ini (see your php.ini and look if is activated)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2787824/php-mail-activation

Answer (score 0):

When your checkbox is not checked - it will not be sent.
Replace

```
$robot = $_POST['robot'];
```

to

```
$robot = isset($_POST['robot']) ? 'yes' : 'no';
```

Comment: Na this isn't the issue. See the comment by @Ivar. OP has bad indentation and the actual error is to do with the mail() function

Comment: Thats removed the `Undefined index: robot in` error but as WillParky93 has said, its not fixed the failure to send. :(

Comment: @bigdave Check the link I commented on your question. That way you can get the actual error message.

Comment: I think you need to check you mail log on your server.

Answer (score 0):

Your Condition Matches the case. Try checking the value of $robot on submit.

```
<input id="capture" name="robot" type="checkbox" value="yes">  

if ($robot != 'yes') {               
        if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $headers)) { 
        echo '<p class="approved"><strong>Your message has been submitted</strong></p>';
    } else { 
        echo '<p class="warning"><strong>Something went wrong!</strong></p>'; 
    }
```

Comment: Na this isn't the issue. See the comment by @Ivar. OP has bad indentation and the actual error is to do with the mail() function

Comment: oh yeah, your'e right.. issue with the mail() function. :p